# Compute $ \lim\limits_{t\to +\infty}\log \frac{1}{t}\int_0^1 \cosh(tf(x))dx. $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Please give some hints and not the whole solution.

> **Problem** Let $f ∈ C([0, 1]).$ Compute
>   $$ \lim\limits_{t\to +\infty}\log \frac{1}{t}\int_0^1 \cosh(tf(x))dx.  $$

Comment: what do we know about $f$? is $C^2$?

Comment: I checked the problem. Everything is what I wrote

Comment: look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115714/calculate-lim-t-to-infty-frac-1t-log-int-01-coshtfx-mathrm-d-x)

Comment: @uniquesolution
 Would you mind telling that why does it suffice to figure out
$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}{1 \over t}\log\int_0^1e^{t|f(x)|}\,dx$??

Comment: @uniquesolution what about the $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}{1 \over t}\log\int_0^1\frac{1}{2}e^{t|f(x)|}\,dx$???

Comment: @alexjo do you have an idea???

Comment: look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115714/calculate-lim-t-to-infty-frac-1t-log-int-01-coshtfx-mathrm-d-x)